# What is the probability that a randomly selected male prefers tea or energy drinks?

Tags: probability, statistics, percentages

Before I begin, This question is from [Algebra nation](https://web.algebranation.com/testyourself/373461)

The data below shows the results of a survey on what types of drinks people prefer in the morning.

[image: Table]

In the past, I've solved questions that are quite similar to this particular question. I asked about it on [Mathematics Stack exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/), and I was informed on how I could solve the problem.

But when I tried using the same method to solve this problem, I came up with answers that were not applicable.

The answer choices are:

A.2%
B.39%
C.24%
D.41%
E.56%

### What I tried

I tried adding up the total amount of people, and dividing the total amount of people by the total amount of males that prefer tea and energy drinks.

Total amount of people who were surveyed=200
Total amount of males that prefer tea and energy drinks=41

200÷41 or 200/41=4.87804

This was obviously wrong, but I wasn't sure, so i kept going. The next step was to convert this terminating decimal into a percentage, in hopes that just maybe it would be converted into one of the answer choices above.

In the end, I only ended up coming up with 487.804%

From what I know, a percentage cannot be above 100%

For example, if I was to say 130% of my students passed the quiz, it wouldn't make sense because a whole is 100%.

So what I need to know is the probability that a randomly selected male prefers tea or energy drinks.

Comment: What's the question?  The header appears to be asking for the probability that a randomly selected male prefers either tea or energy drinks (and not coffee).  That's $\frac {41}{56}=0.732142857$.  There doesn't appear to be any question in the body of your post.  i don't know why you'd look at the entire population when you are only asking about the males.

Comment: I repeated the question at the end of the body of the post. The question is "What is the probability that a randomly selected male prefers either tea or energy drinks".

Comment: Well, that's $0.732142857$ as I said.

Comment: Where does the figure of 200 people come from?

Comment: Because when you add up the number of people who took the survey, you get 200.

Comment: Reverse engineering the question from the official options, if you were actually asking "what's the probability that an individual, selected uniformly at random from this sample population, was a male who preferred either tea or coffee?" then the answer would be $\frac {41}{100}=41\%$ which, at least, is one of the options.

Comment: As this is a survey... a sample... this is not a probability but a relative frequency in the available sample.

Comment: Oh, ok I see what I did wrong. I added the total along with 100.

Comment: Like [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537100/what-is-the-probability-that-you-pick-hersheys-or-reeses), your division is upside-down