# What is the probability that you pick Hershey's or Reese's?

Tags: probability

The following problem is an ACT prep question from [Algebra Nation](https://web.algebranation.com/)

---

### It is Given that:

A candy bar box at Publix consists of 12 snickers bars, 10 Hershey's bars, and 6 Reese's. If you pick a candy bar from the box without looking, **what is the probability that it will be a Hershey's or a Reese's?**

The following answer choices are provided:

A.³⁄₇

B.⁵⁄₁₄

C.³⁄₁₄

D.⁴⁄₇

E.1

### What I know about Probability

A probability is a number that reflects the chance or likelihood that a particular event will occur.

Usually, with probability problems about a certain event occurring we divide the total number of ways the event can occur by the total number of possible outcomes.

### What I've tried

Using the information I've provided about probability, I know that the first step would be to add the number of candy bars because each candy bar represents each outcome.

*12+10+6=28*

So there are 28 candy bars in total.

Since the question is asking for the probability of choosing a Reese's or a Hershey's, I tried adding up the amount of Hershey's and Reese's.

*10+6=16*

But this is where I think I made a mistake.

The next step was to divide the outcomes by the sum of the Reese's and Hershey's and this is what I came up with:

²⁸⁄₁₆=⁷⁄₄

⁷⁄₄ is not an applicable answer choice, so I concluded that my answer was incorrect.

I suppose that my way of solving the problem was inaccurate and that there is a possibility that the information given under the "What I know about Probability" header is false.

Comment: Why did you say $\frac{28}{16}$ rather than $\frac{16}{28}$?  You seem to have been confused by what "the total number of ways the event can occur" and "the total number of possible outcomes" mean, or possibly "divided ... by ...".

Comment: I thought that 'the total number of ways the event can occur' meant the number of total outcomes. But now I see where I went wrong.